# How can I find how far above the ground is point $A$ with gradients?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, slope

This is the problem. I feel like there is something missing I can't relate how we use gradients to find the point

[image]

Comment: Put things in a coordinate system. Suppose the lower left point is $(0,0)$, the upper right point is $(65,65)$, and point $A$ is $(x,y)$. Each of the given slopes gives you an equation involving $x$ and $y$.